# How Remix IDE compiles smart contract code to ABI and bytecode?

Tags: web3js, remix, truffle, ethers.js, hardhat

I am building a DApp where user uploads his smart contract code file and his smart contract gets deployed using his private key ( After he connects his metamask account to the DApp ) . How RemixIDE is able to compile contract code to abi and bytecode ? I want to have the same functionality so that I can later deploy the compiled bytecode to Blockchain using web3js or ethersjs .